# How to open .raw file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to open this fixed.raw file (can be found here: http://elastix.isi.uu.nl/download/elastix_example_v4.8.zip) on Matlab.

I tried:

```
row=256;  col=256;
fin=fopen('fixed.raw','r');
I=fread(fin, [col row],'uint8=>uint8'); 
Z=I';
k=imshow(Z)
```

An image appears, but it isn't properly aligned. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by 'not properly aligned'? What is the desired output?

Comment: Your raw file comes with a mhd description file. Search for mhd at matlab file exchange and you will find multiple implementations to read the file.

Comment: Seems like your image is `512*256` and not `256*256`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your image is bigger than you expected. Try running :

```
row=256;  col=512;
fin=fopen('fixed.raw','r');
I=fread(fin, [col row],'uint8=>uint8'); 
Z=I';
k=imshow(Z)
```

Comment: That works, thank you!